# Expected object of scalar type Float but got scalar type Long for argument #2 'mat1' in call to _th_addmm

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch

The error `Expected object of scalar type Float but got scalar type Long for argument #2 'mat1' in call to _th_addmm` is being displayed after running the code below.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import nltk  
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer 
nltk.download('wordnet') 
import re 
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader, TensorDataset
```

... (created a pandas dataframe containing a 'tweet', 'sentiment' and 47 one-hot bag of words cols)

```
# create train_target data set containing just the target
train_target = torch.tensor(df_train['sentiment'].values, dtype=torch.long)

# create train predictor features data set containing just the predictor features
train = torch.tensor(df_train.drop(['tweet','sentiment'], axis = 1).values, dtype=torch.long)

# convert to torch tensor and define data loader (train)
train_tensor = TensorDataset(train, train_target) 
trainset = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_tensor, batch_size=2, shuffle=False)

# create test_target data set containing just the target
test_target = torch.tensor(df_test['sentiment'].values, dtype=torch.long)

# create test predictor features data set containing just the predictor features
test = torch.tensor(df_test.drop(['tweet','sentiment'], axis = 1).values, dtype=torch.long)

# convert to torch tensor and define data loader (test)
test_tensor = TensorDataset(test, test_target) 
testset = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(test_tensor, batch_size=2, shuffle=False)

input_length = 47

class Net(nn.Module):   # create a new class called Net that inherits from nn's "Module" class

    # initialise our Net class
    def __init__(self):    
        super().__init__()    # run the initialisation function of the nn.Module class (the parent class)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input_length, 768)   # define the first fully connected layer. 
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(768, 768)    # define the 2nd layer
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(768, 2)    # output layer. 2 classes so output is size 2

    # define how data will flow through feed-forward network
    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))  # x becomes the output of running the 1st layer, after relu activation is applied
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))    # x then becomes the output of the 2nd layer...
        x = self.fc3(x)    

        return F.log_softmax(x, dim=1)  # we want a probability distribution across the 2 classes so using softmax
                                        # dim=1 because we want the probabilities across the classes, not
                                        # the batches

# create a Net object called net
net = Net()
print(net)   

# Train the model (net)
optimiser = optim.Adam(net.parameters(),  # net.parameters is everything thats adjustable in our model
                      lr=0.001)  # learning rate 
epochs = 10
for epoch in range(epochs):
    for batch_data in trainset:
        X, y = batch_data  # set X as the input and y as the label
        net.zero_grad() # start with gradients of zero
        output = net(X.view(-1, input_length))  # run the model (could put batch size in instead of -1)
        loss = F.nll_loss(output, y)   # how wrong were we? Calculate loss. 
        loss.backward()    # backpropagate the loss (how much did each weight contribute to the loss?)
        optimiser.step()    # adjust the weights based on the backpropagation
    print('Epoch: ', epoch, ' Loss: ', loss)
```

What do I need to do to fix this? I'm trying to create a neural network to do sentiment classification on some text data from tweets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inputs to the `nn.Linear` layers, and therefore your model, need to be floats, not longs.

You need to change the features to use `dtype=torch.float`:

```py
train = torch.tensor(df_train.drop(['tweet','sentiment'], axis = 1).values, dtype=torch.float)

test = torch.tensor(df_test.drop(['tweet','sentiment'], axis = 1).values, dtype=torch.float)
```

That only applies to the input features, whereas your targets need to remain `torch.long` for the NLL loss.